# How to get the xy coordinate of an image=(0,0) from in the Big box(div)?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem... I'm using visual studio 2008...

I want to ask, how to get the xy coordinate of an image=(0,0) from in the Big box (div)? Because when the image is drag to the end of the box it will give me x=8 and y=8... Instead of x=0 and y=0...

Please help me! Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
$('#dragThis').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    // sets the cursor apperance
    containment: '#box',
    drag: function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = Math.abs(offset.left);
        var yPos = Math.abs(offset.top);
        $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
        $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {

        // Show dropped position.
        var Stoppos = $(this).position();
        var left = Math.abs(Stoppos.left);
        var top = Math.abs(Stoppos.top);
        $('#posX').text('left: ' + left);
        $('#posY').text('top: ' + top);
    }

});​
```

This is link... The box I've said actually is a panel.

http://jsfiddle.net/qx5K7/

Answer (score 0):

You had an incorrect tag **asp**, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qx5K7/2/) it works